# Intent returned to Xamarin android activity has non-null Data, but the result of Intent.Data is null

Tags: android, xamarin, android-intent

I'm trying to write a file using Android File Storage and the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` intent. The intent runs, I select a file, and the empty file is created. My activity `OnActivityResult` is called with a non-null intent, with the correct event code passed in `StartActivityForResult()`, and with `Result.OK`.

I can even see in the debugger that the intent has non-null `Data` field: a `Android.Net.UriInvoker` with the value `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/62` for example. However, when I call `Intent.Data`, the value returned is `null` so I can't write to the newly-created file.

Am I using the intent incorrectly, is there a different way to extract the URI from the intent here?

```cs
        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

           if (requestCode == ExportRdeAction)
            {
                if ((resultCode == Result.Ok) && (intent != null))
                {
                    // breakpoint here: Intent.Data is set
                    if (Intent.Data != null)
                    {
                        // don't get here :(
                        Stream outputStream = ContentResolver.OpenOutputStream(Intent.Data);
                        ExportStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                        ExportStream.Close();
                        outputStream.Close();
                        ExportStream = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which target framework android version that you used? If you used android 9.0, please add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in `<application>` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml.`

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thanks, I have target SDK version 28, minimum version 21.

Comment: Just tried that anyway, and I get error APT2260.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to JPobst on the Xamarin team who showed me I'm being dense. There's a local variable called `intent`, and a field on the activity called `Intent`. I was trying to use `Intent.Data` which isn't set, and `intent.Data` is fine.